# Checking certain row from a table which is referenced to another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I know that the question will not make any sense at all to what I am asking, but what I mean is that..... To make it more clear, I will illustrate my problem in examples:

I have a `userpost` table that contains posts from different users.

**userpost** table:

```
 +---------+--------+--------------+
 |  postId | userId | postMessage  |
 +---------+--------+--------------+
 |       1 |      3 | someText     |
 |       2 |      5 | someText     |
 |       3 |      2 | sometext     |
 |       5 |      6 | someText     |
 +---------+--------+--------------+
```

(**!REMEMBER that** `userId` **is being referenced to** `users` table)

I have another table called `favorites` where `postId` is being referenced from `userpost` table:

**favorites** table:

```
+---------+--------+
|  postId | userId |
+---------+--------+
|       1 |      5 |  
|       3 |      2 |  
+---------+--------+
```

What I want is to grab all the data from `userpost` and check if a certain userpost has been Favorited by (`WHERE userId = 5`) let's say

I tried using this query but that's not what I want!

```
    SELECT *,
    (SELECT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM `favorites` INNER JOIN `userpost` on 
    favourites.postId = userpost.postId WHERE favorites.postId = 1 
    AND   favorites.userId = 5)) AS isFavourited FROM userpost;
```

This is the result of the following query:

```
+---------+--------+-------------+--------------+
|  postId | userId | postMessage | isFavourited |
+---------+--------+-------------+--------------+
|       1 |      3 | someText    |            1 |  
|       2 |      5 | someText    |            1 | 
|       3 |      2 | someText    |            1 |  
|       5 |      3 | someText    |            1 | 
+---------+--------+-------------+--------------+
```

I know that I am making the mistake inside the query by using:

`(WHERE favorites.postId = 1 AND favorites.userId = 5)`

which does return true.

I will give you an example of **what I want**:

Lets say `(userId = 5)` wants to grab all the `userpost` and we must get the  result below:

```
+---------+--------+-------------+--------------+
|  postId | userId | postMessage | isFavourited |
+---------+--------+-------------+--------------+
|       1 |      3 | someText    |            1 |  
|       2 |      5 | someText    |            0 | 
|       3 |      2 | someText    |            0 |  
|       5 |      3 | someText    |            0 | 
+---------+--------+-------------+--------------+
```

---

Comment: @JayBlanchard I already gave what I tried. Read the question carefully

Comment: Ah - it got lost in the mass of stuff.

Comment: If we're talking about userId = 3, then I would expect userId = 3 to feature somewhere in the query. Are you bonkers?

Comment: @Strawberry My bad :) but got what I needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT *, 
    postId IN 
        (SELECT postId FROM favourites WHERE userId = 5) 
    AS isFavourited
FROM userPost
```

Your query checks that a row exists where user 5 favourites post 1; not where user 5 favorites the post being selected in that row of the return.

Comment: Wow! Works perfectly! But can you explain how your query works @amanning

Comment: This is likely to be hideously slow on larger data sets.

Comment: @Strawberry Really! I am exactly using larger data sets for my social network. Any suggestion??

Comment: @mikaeel The inner `SELECT` returns the posts that your user has favorited.  For each post in the results, the `IN` clause returns whether or not it's one of these favorited posts.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do something like this if I understand what you're asking :

```
select up.*, case when f.postId is null then "0" else "1" end as isFavourited 
from userpost up
left join favourites f on f.postId  = up.postId  and f.userId = up.userId
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Can't choose between to right answers

Comment: @mikaeel FWIW, this is the one I'd pick. My guess is that, appropriately indexed, it will scale better.